# What happened to stack2rss.stackexchange.com?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, feed

Since Monday, I think about the time when all Stack Exchange servers had been in read-only mode, http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/ has seemed to be dead.

Did I miss the announcement about its closing, or is there hope for a cure?

If this was intentional, all answers mentioning stack2rss here and on all subsites need to be edited!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Projects such as [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/) and the [Election Statistics page](http://elections.stackexchange.com) didn't make the long journey cross-country to Oregon when the network failed over, so they're unavailable until the NYC data center is operational again or they're manually moved.

Currently there's [no known ETA](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/31/an-update-on-sandy/) for the transition back to NYC, but you can keep up-to-date on developments by following the [Server Fault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/), as well as the [Peer 1 recovery forum thread](http://forums.peer1.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=7532).

In light of this indeterminite downtime, our [resident disembodied head](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [has also been asked](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1155767#1155767) to remind the sysadmins about these services, so there's an implied chance that they may join the rest of the network on the West Coast should the situation in NYC not quickly improve.

Comment: Oh, I see … I didn’t know, that the data center is in NYC, so another Sandy victim, hopefully temporary.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, useful for the future – but hopefully not necessary. ;-)

Comment: FWIW, there's no known ETA for NYC to get back to being NYC.

Comment: There's also some updates at http://status.squarespace.com/

Comment: Personally, I'd have been assisted if http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source had been edited to reflect the acknowledged downtime.