# User's network-wide activity RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, recent-activity, feed

I think it would be useful to have an RSS feed of network-wide activity, or at least posts, for a given network user, corresponding to the information available in the current network activity tab, e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c?tab=activity.

I propose something like `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/305991`.

I found [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stackexchange-and-stac) which, while old, seems accurate (at least the feeds listed there are valid) and confirms that a network feed does not exist. There are also various related discussions linked to from there, (such as the [abandoned stack2rss project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153229/what-happened-to-stack2rss-stackexchange-com/153230#153230)), which I will not re-list here.

I looked for other feature requests for this, but all I found was [RSS feed of user's posts across the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238494/rss-feed-of-users-posts-across-the-network), which didn't seem to take off, and [Additional RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242989/additional-rss-or-atom-feeds?lq=1), which is a broader scope than this request and primarily asks for more specific, subdivided feeds.